# What is the correct counter for "frames"?

Tags: counters

What is the correct counter word to use when talking about a number of "frames" in a time? Ex: a time in a video game.

Answer (score 1):

There is no commonly used counter word for some foreign words such as "frames". フレーム will simply be added after the number e.g. １フレーム, ２フレーム, and so on. It is usually pronounced as いちフレーム, にフレーム...

Other examples of this are セット or タイプ, although for these it's easier to rephrase the sentence to make sure of the general counter 一つ、二つ...

Answer (score 1):

When you are talking about individual frames of something like a movie or manga, there's the word 「**コマ**」, but for video game frame rates and whatnot, I think you'll find most people just use **フレームレート** and **fps**.